# Question about Assumptions of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am reading "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue measure" and "Real analysis" by Folland.

The statement for LDCT from two books is the following:
Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of (Lebesgue-) integrable functions which converges (almost everywhere) to a real-valued function $f$. If there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $\left| f_n \right| \le g$ for all n, then $f$ is integrable and
$\int f\ d\boldsymbol\mu$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f\ d\boldsymbol\mu$.

My question is: Why do we need to assume each $f_n$ is integrable? In my thought if we just assume that $f_n$ is measurable, then we have $f_n$ is integrable from that assumption with another assumption that each $f_n$ is dominated by an integrable function $g$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, 100% right.

Comment: @geetha290krm Then do we need not to assume that f is measurable, too? As limit of a sequence of measurable functions is also measurable...

Comment: It is not even stated that $f$ is measurable. It says $f$ is real valued, and that  is enough.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for answering. I have just checked both books. Bartle's book states that $f$ is meausrable but Folland's book omitted it.

Comment: @geetha290krm I came up with this question reading the proof of Corollary 5.9 of Bartle's which is the same proposition of Theorem 2.27 of Folland. I wondered why the proof of the Bartle's book showed integrability to use LDCT if the question of my original post is true. As the proof of Folland's book doesn't contain that part, it is redudant, I think.